# VBScript: WshShell.SendKeys "^{ADD}" gives "Invalid Procedure Call Code: 800A0005" error

Tags: vbscript

Below code should be self-explanatory (sending ctrl-numADD key combination); however, I'm obviously doing something wrong.  The full error produced from the below code is:

```
Line: 4
Char: 1
Error:  Invalid procedule call or argument
Code: 800A005
```

How can I send this key combination without producing an error?

PS: The code is at least able to change focus to correct window before trying to do a sendkeys.

```
 Dim WshellObj   
 set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   
 WshShell.AppActivate "Logs"   
 WshShell.SendKeys "^{ADD}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you get that particular error, but you are trying to use and invalid key sequence with the SendKeys methods.  "{ADD}" is not a valid code.

You should be using this instead.

```
Dim WshellObj
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "Logs"
WshShell.SendKeys "^+"
```

This will send a + sign.  SendKeys does not have support for number pad specific keys.

Comment: if this is an answer, it would be more helpful with a code correction